# Grab textbox salesforce ID and display somewhere else on same page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I have a apex:textbox which renders on a visualforce page with a SF ID.

I need to grab the SF ID on the same page load and place into a link.

eg: I need this:

```
<input id="j_id0:mainpage:edit:querysection:j_id67:0:val1" maxlength="99" name="j_id0:mainpage:edit:querysection:j_id67:0:val1" size="20" type="text" value="Madrid,London">
```

I need the name or ID from above to apper in a link next to the same textbox:

```
<img src="test.jpg" onclick="myPopup2('/GenericPopUp?pv=j_id0:mainpage:edit:querysection:j_id67:0:val1', 300, 300, true)">
```

Can you help?

Comment: Im passing it because i want to pass a value from the popup back to the parent, to the textbox above.

Answer (score 2):

It was just

```
{!$Component.val1}
```

DOH